# How To Add Add To Shopcart Button In Opencart Product Description

Tags: opencart

I am trying to insert a shop cart button at the bottom of the product description in Opencart verson 1.5.4 and am using the default theme.

I looked at the source code for a particular product and copied this information from the source code into the bottom of the product description.

```
       <div class="cart">
    <div>Qty:          <input type="text" name="quantity" size="2" value="1" />
      <input type="hidden" name="product_id" size="2" value="85" />
      &nbsp;
      <input type="button" value="Add to Cart" id="button-cart" class="button" />
    </div>
    <div><span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;- OR -&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></div>
    <div><a onclick="addToWishList('85');">Add to Wish List</a><br />
      <a onclick="addToCompare('85');">Add to Compare</a></div>
          </div>
```

When I click on the add to shop cart button, nothing happens.

But when I click on the add to wish list and compare , the product is added to the respective lists.

What am I missing?

Should I be using a different code?

Can anyone help me solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Chang you add to shopping cart button , with this 
`<a onclick="addToCart('<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>');" class="button"><?php echo $button_cart; ?></a>`.

Hope it will works for you.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the Add to Cart code button uses an ID that is linked within a DIV. So jQuery is not lookning for #button-cart - it is looking for, example cart. addform #button-cart and also your missing some variables that need to be nested too.. Update your post with the full version of the product.tpl please too

This is the code you need to be using for moving the Add To Cart Button:

```
  <div class="cart">
    <div><?php echo $text_qty; ?>
      <input type="text" name="quantity" size="2" value="<?php echo $minimum; ?>" />
      <input type="hidden" name="product_id" size="2" value="<?php echo $product_id; ?>" />
      &nbsp;
      <input type="button" value="<?php echo $button_cart; ?>" id="button-cart" class="button" />
      <span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo $text_or; ?>&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
      <span class="links"><a onclick="addToWishList('<?php echo $product_id; ?>');"><?php echo $button_wishlist; ?></a><br />
        <a onclick="addToCompare('<?php echo $product_id; ?>');"><?php echo $button_compare; ?></a></span>
    </div>
    <?php if ($minimum > 1) { ?>
    <div class="minimum"><?php echo $text_minimum; ?></div>
    <?php } ?>
  </div>
```

But make sure the `.product-info` and `#cart` ID and Class child elements are supported within your new DIV move. Why? Look at this jQuery, it depends on them to find the values - having said this - you could change it too.

```
$('#button-cart').bind('click', function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?route=checkout/cart/add',
        type: 'post',
        data: $('.product-info input[type=\'text\'], .product-info input[type=\'hidden\'], .product-info input[type=\'radio\']:checked, .product-info input[type=\'checkbox\']:checked, .product-info select, .product-info textarea'),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(json) {
            $('.success, .warning, .attention, information, .error').remove();

            if (json['error']) {
                if (json['error']['option']) {
                    for (i in json['error']['option']) {
                        $('#option-' + i).after('<span class="error">' + json['error']['option'][i] + '</span>');
                    }
                }
            } 

            if (json['success']) {
                $('#notification').html('<div class="success" style="display: none;">' + json['success'] + '<img src="catalog/view/theme/default/image/close.png" alt="" class="close" /></div>');

                $('.success').fadeIn('slow');

                $('#cart-total').html(json['total']);

                $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow'); 
            }   
        }
    });
});
```

And updated version according to your needs would be:

```
/*
Notice I have changed the DIV to assign div#cart
So it looks for <div id="cart">
But make sure options are available for the error response
and validation
*/

$('#button-cart').bind('click', function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?route=checkout/cart/add',
        type: 'post',
        data: $('div#cart input[type=\'text\'], div#cart input[type=\'hidden\'], div#cart input[type=\'radio\']:checked, div#cart input[type=\'checkbox\']:checked, div#cart select, div#cart textarea'),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(json) {
            $('.success, .warning, .attention, information, .error').remove();

            if (json['error']) {
                if (json['error']['option']) {
                    for (i in json['error']['option']) {
                        $('#option-' + i).after('<span class="error">' + json['error']['option'][i] + '</span>');
                    }
                }
            } 

            if (json['success']) {
                $('#notification').html('<div class="success" style="display: none;">' + json['success'] + '<img src="catalog/view/theme/default/image/close.png" alt="" class="close" /></div>');
                $('.success').fadeIn('slow');
                $('#cart-total').html(json['total']);
                $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow'); 
            }   
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

Do you mean "move" the add to cart button? or simply copy the exesting one so there's two #button-cart in your page?

If the first, the solution from @TheBlackBenzKid should work as you expected.
But if you want to copy the existing button, you should modify the selector so it use class (.button-cart). I hope this help.

Sorry for the late reply. Based on your answer:

> I would like to copy the existing one so that there are two buttons in the page

What I mean in *modify the selector so it use class (.button-cart)* is you should change your ajax trigger to match 2 selector (because now you have 2 'trigger', the top "Add to cart" and at the bottom that you copy to).

First modify your add-to-cart to `<input type="button" value="Add to Cart" id="" class="button-cart button" />`

see, we don't use `id="button-cart"` anymore, instead, we use `button-cart` as our class attribut (`class="button-cart button"`). By using class, we can declare another element with same class (i.e your 'add-to-cart' button at the bottom of your product description).

Then modify your Ajax script. The original ajax script is:

```
$('#button-cart').bind('click', function() {
$.ajax({
// another code
```

});

Change to:

```
$('.button-cart').bind('click', function() {
$.ajax({
// another code
```

});

id use `#` and class use`.`. I hope this help you.

Comment: Thank you.  I would like to copy the existing one so that there are two buttons in the page. The second one will be at the bottom of the product description for each product. I am not a programmer. I am a copy an paster so do please excuse my muddled approach to this. Would you be so kind as to show me what the code would look like to "modify the selector so it uses class (button cart).  Thank you.